# Is there a way to stack two columns in excel but alternating numbers?

Tags: excel

I have multiple columns of data with spaces in between them (see simplified image below).  I am curious if there is a way to stack the two columns while simultaneously alternating the numbers from each column.

[image]

I am hoping to place the 11 under the 1, 22 under the 2, 33 under the 3...etc. If I need to get rid of the spaces between the number I can figure that out! I have attempted VSTACK but maybe I am doing it incorrectly.  Any and all help would be appreciated!

The only thing I tried with little success was VSTACK

Comment: I deleted it because you left the comment about more specifically and did exactly what I was asking for so I did not think the comment was warranted!  My apologies!

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=TOCOL(A1:B17,1)
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Select the values in Column C (not the entire column, just the cells with values) and Copy (ctrl-c)

[image]

Select cell B2 and then from the Paste Menu select Paste Special

[image]

Select Skip Blanks then click OK

[image]

[image]

Comment: I didn't know this trick, pretty cool and fast. Upvoted